# Merging two Arrays using index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays I would like to merge in to one. How can I do this ?

```
Array A ["Chicken", "cow", "lamb"]
Array B ["egg", "beef", "chop"]
```

Desired outcome:

```
Array C ["Chicken egg", "cow beef", "lamb chop"]
```

Answer (score 5):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is useful for writing this cleanly.

http://jsbin.com/heromuruka/1/edit?js,console

```
var a = ["Chicken", "cow", "lamb"],
    b = ["egg", "beef", "chop"];


var c = a.map(function (e, i) {
  return e + ' ' + b[i]; 
});
```

The value of `e` is the current element, and the value of `i` is the current index.

Comment: This is very clean. I will keep this in mind if I ever need to do something like this.

Comment: Cheers for the edit - I cleaned it up slightly for clarification of terms.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your arrays are defined like this:

```
var arrayA = ["Chicken", "cow", "lamb"];
var arrayB = ["egg", "beef", "chop"];
var arrayC = [];
```

You can use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    arrayC[i] = arrayA[i] + ' ' + arrayB[i];
}
```

See a working example below:

```js
var arrayA = ["Chicken", "cow", "lamb"];
var arrayB = ["egg", "beef", "chop"];
var arrayC = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  arrayC[i] = arrayA[i] + ' ' + arrayB[i];
}

console.log(arrayC);
```